# How to hide a UISearchBar by code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar on top of my TableView. The tableView is showing multiple data at different times. The user can select the data which is shown in the TableView.

Normally the user can search his data but at one case the data is an overview (kind of diagrams or facts and statistics) so in this view I want to hide the search bar.

I have tried to hide it with:

```
  searchBar.hidden = true
```

but in this case I get a white view instead of the searchBar (the background view?).

So to make it simple I want to know how to avoid that the user search something and I hope to get it done by hiding the searchBar.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea, offset the `UITableView` by the height of the search bar height on loading the view,  when you need to display it move the `UITableView` back down.

When you load the view

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -40 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

then when you want to display the search bar

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

Adjust the height values as necassary

Comment: First you have to change -40 to +45 to get it working. The result looks fine but if you start scrolling up the white view (or the search bar) is back again